# Business Logic on UI vs Cron/Background Job

Tags: design, cron

In our application some business logic execute when customer do an action on UI and some business logic execute on a cron jobs.

I have read some where that we should only keep minimal business logic on UI and let the cron jobs do the heavy work, so that we can immediately show a message to the customer without making him/her wait and do the intensive work in cron jobs.

On the other hand, I also read some where that we should execute all the business logic upfront so there is no need for any cron job.

What is the common option companies are following/practicing in software engineering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read some where that we should only keep minimal business logic on UI

I have read that as well. The chief "some where" I recall is from Robert Martin:

> **The upshot**
> The upshot is simply this: The GUI is a detail. The web is a GUI. So the web is a detail.
> And, as an architect, you want to put details like that behind boundaries that keep them
> separate from your core business logic.
>
> Think about it this way: The WEB is an IO device. In the 1960s, we learned the value of
> writing applications that were device independent. The motivation for that
> independence has not changed. The web is not an exception to that rule.
>
> Or is it? The argument can be made that a GUI, like the web, is so unique and rich that it
> is absurd to pursue a device-independent architecture. When you think about the
> intricacies of JavaScript validation or drag-and-drop AJAX calls, or any of the plethora
> of other widgets and gadgets you can put on a web page, it’s easy to argue that device
> independence is impractical.
>
> To some extent, this is true. The interaction between the application and the GUI is
> “chatty” in ways that are quite specific to the kind of GUI you have. The dance between
> a browser and a web application is different from the dance between a desktop GUI and
> its application. Trying to abstract out that dance, the way devices are abstracted out of
> UNIX, seems unlikely to be possible.
>
> But another boundary between the UI and the application can be abstracted. The
> business logic can be thought of as a suite of use cases, each of which performs some
> function on behalf of a user. Each use case can be described based on the input data, the
> processing preformed, and the output data.
>
> At some point in the dance between the UI and the application, the input data can be
> said to be complete, allowing the use case to be executed. Upon completion, the
> resultant data can be fed back into the dance between the UI and the application.
>
> The complete input data and the resultant output data can be placed into data structures
> and used as the input values and output values for a process that executes the use case.
> With this approach, we can consider each use case to be operating the IO device of the
> UI in a device-independent manner.
>
> **CONCLUSION**
> This kind of abstraction is not easy, and it will likely take several iterations to get just
> right. But it is possible. And since the world is full of marketing geniuses, it’s not hard
> to make the case that it’s often very necessary.
>
> [Clean Architecture - Chapter 31 - The web is a detail](http://prof.mau.ac.ir/images/Uploaded_files/Clean%20Architecture_%20A%20Craftsman%E2%80%99s%20Guide%20to%20Software%20Structure%20and%20Design-Pearson%20Education%20(2018)%5B7615523%5D.PDF)

However, It isn't as simple as UI vs cron job. Just because it's client side doesn't mean it's in the UI. Just because it's server side doesn't mean it's a cron job.

Your client side code is free to have layers. That is, separations, that protect business rules from changes to how the UI is presented. This limits the impact of change and enables testing. Even if it's all happening client side.

So you can execute business logic upfront. You see this when given feedback on the strength of a new password, or that an email is invalid, before hitting submit.

But when you're told that a username is already in use that usually isn't done client side. That usually comes from the server. And it isn't a cron job. That was likely feedback from a business rule being executed on the server that was trying to create an account for you and failed. That doesn't happen in a cron and it doesn't happen client side. This happens server side and it happens on demand. It's likely a background job. Depends how the service was run on the server.

I don't know where you read that "we should execute all the business logic upfront". It's a lofty but unreasonable goal. The main reason batch processing will always be a thing is because 3rd party software drops files without providing events to hook into. You end up polling for them. It's much better to drop a file and then call something to deal with it than to just drop the file and make something else poll for it. But sometimes you don't control the code that drops the file.

There's also things like verifying that processes are still up and respawning them if they aren't. Cron is mostly used for system maintenance type work. It can end up as part of the applications business rules but this isn't typical. Mostly because Cron isn't something an application controls. That's the system controlling an application.

Background jobs are just jobs that aren't tying up the console on the server computer. They can be moved to the foreground without impacting users.

Some things just can't be pushed out client side. That might be because it would require sending out confidential data or algorithms. It might be because the client doesn't have the resources the server does.

So really, the big difference is which computer is the code running on. The clients computer or the server computer. But both can have business rules in them and still be separated from the UI.

The UI, after all, is just a definition of what the user see's on the screen. Everything it does can be simplified down to talking to a testable API. Business rules do not have to live here.

Comment: My UI is web. So, my code is running on server side not on client(JS). The main question is whether we should put all heavy business logic/validations on web server side or move them from web server side to a background/cron job that pick transaction from web server side using a distributed queue.

Comment: @user960567, background/cron jobs are ideal for tasks that are not time sensitive (nobody is waiting for the task to finish) and/or don't need input from a user. If a user is waiting for the outcome or they need to supply a fair amount of data to it, then it is typically better to start the task as soon as the user asks it.